# Couldn't match expected type ‘(Char, Bool) -> Bool’ with actual type ‘Char’

Tags: haskell

I am learning section tautology checker in chapter8 of the book ["Programming in Haskell"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1316626229).

[image]

There is code which mentions to

```
eval :: Subst -> Prop -> Bool
eval _ (Const b) = b
eval s (Var x) = find x s
eval s (Not p) = not (eval s p)
eval s (And p q) = eval s p && eval s q
eval s (Imply p q) = eval s p <= eval s q
```

I'm getting the below error when I do compile this code.

```
tautology_checker.hs:26:23: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(Char, Bool) -> Bool’
              with actual type ‘Char’
    • In the first argument of ‘find’, namely ‘x’
      In the expression: find x s
      In an equation for ‘eval’: eval s (Var x) = find x s
   |
26 | eval s (Var x) = find x s
   |
```

I've check for spell correction and typo. It seems to be correct.

My code is [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/ProgrammingInHaskell/blob/master/chapter8/tautology_checker.hs).

Please help me how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `find` that ends up being used in your code comes from `Data.List` and has signature `find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a`. This function tries to find an element of the given list that matches the given predicate.

However, from the way this function is used in your code, you seem to be assuming the signature `find :: k -> Assoc k v -> v`, with the semantics of locating a value by key in an associative list. This is how I would implement such function:

```
find :: Eq k => k -> Assoc k v -> v
find k ((k', v) : _) | k == k' = v
find k (_ : tail) = find k tail
```

I don't have this book, so I can't tell for sure, but my guess is that the book actually defines this function somewhere earlier, probably at the same place it defines the type `Assoc` itself. You have included the definition of `Assoc` in your code, but forgot to include the definition of `find`.

Also note that the function `find` defined this way is *partial*: it doesn't know what to return when the given associative list doesn't contain the given key. In order for it to be total, it would need to return `Maybe v` instead of just `v`. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Indeed the book has given the definition of find function very next to `type Assoc`. I noticed  `type Assoc` but not `find` function. Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you’re inadvertently using the Prelude’s standard function `find`, of type:

```
Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Maybe a
```

Or, specialised to lists:

```
(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
```

Whereas the book wants you to use some *other* `find` function, probably defined elsewhere in the text, of a type like:

```
(Eq a) => a -> [(a, b)] -> b
```

Or, in your case:

```
Char -> [(Char, Bool)] -> Bool
```

You’re giving it `x` as its first argument, which is of type `Char`, but it’s expecting a function of type `(Char, Bool) -> Bool`, because `(Char, Bool)` is the element type of the list. That’s the source of the type error you got.

You can replace `find x s` using the standard function `lookup`:

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

Combined with something like `fromJust` (which throws an error when a variable isn’t bound), e.g., `fromJust (lookup x s)`. You could also use something like `find' x s = fromMaybe (error ("unbound variable '" ++ [x] ++ "'")) (lookup x s)` for a more detailed error message, or `fromMaybe False` (which assumes unbound variables are `False`), using `fromMaybe` from `Data.Maybe`.